# Act on lines changed by previous command

Tags: cursor-motions, range, object-motions

Is there a way to target the set of lines changed in the previous command? Say I do a search and replace, bulk indent, or some other command that affects either a series or  scattered collection of lines. Next, I want to run a command that targets those lines only. Is there a range shortcut or other motion command to target the previous action?

Comment: I doubt whether it is possible with hour function. If you would have used dd like command, it would be difficult to find and use. By creating functions,  we can remember the line numbers and perform on them

Comment: `'[` and `']` mark the first line and the last line of the last change but individual lines are not remembered in a useful way. Useful in the context of your question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As @romainl said, you can use the `[` and `]` marks for this purpose, e.g.:

```
nnoremap gc `[v`]
```

Pressing <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> visually select the previous change.

```
:'[,']s/var_name/varName/g
```

Replace in the last modified lines every `var_name` with `varName`

If you want to use it in your function you can get informations about the last changed lines like so:

```
let firstline = line("'[")
let lastline = line("']")
```

See: `:h ']` and `:h '[`